# How to put one text.txt file line by line? And there are some errors

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I want to know what is wrong with my code.
So I basically trying to put two text.txt file line by line, but something wrong is going on here, and I have tried many times, i do not know what is going on. Could anyone help me with this? Appreciated!

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv)==3:
     with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1, open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
            for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
                print("{0}\t{1}".format(x.strip(), y.strip()))
elif len(sys.argv)==2:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as F1:
        for x in zip(F1):
          print("{}".format(x.strip()))
```

> The error says: File "stickytape.py", line 9
>   print("{}".format(x.strip())) ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and
>   spaces in indentation

Comment: align your code, you got more spaces between `with` and `for` (second block) than `for` and `print`, put your curser before the last `print` and press backspace twice...

Comment: Indentation is part of pythons code. The error `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` tells you you either mix "tabs" and "spaces" to indent the source code **or** you are changing the length (using 3 spaces, then 4 spaces - invalid indentation)... use some kind of editor that shows you spaces and tabs and fix it.